# How to hide and show elements in table row to allow in-line editing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, show-hide

I'm trying to implement in-line editing of table data that is generated via php.

Here's the php code that generates a row

```
<tr class="zipCodeRow">
<td>
    <a class="hideOnEdit zipCodeFormSubmit" name="' . $rowZipCodes['id'] . '" href="#">Edit</a>
    <input type="submit" class="hideOnLoad submitEditZipCodeRow zipCodeFormSubmit" id="submitEditZipCodeRow-' . $rowZipCodes['id'] . '" value="Save Edits" /><br />
    <input type="submit" class="hideOnLoad cancelEditZipCodeRow zipCodeFormSubmit" value="Cancel Edit" />
</td>
<td>
    <input type="checkbox" class="chkDeleteZipCodeRow zipCodeFormSubmit" name="deleteZipCodeRow[]" value"' . $rowZipCodes['id'] . '" />
</td>
<td>
    <label class="hideOnEdit">' . $rowZipCodes['state'] . '</label>
    <input type="text" class="hideOnLoad" size="20" maxlength="50" value="' . $rowZipCodes['state'] . '"
</td>
<td>
    <label class="hideOnEdit">' . $rowZipCodes['county'] . '</label>
    <input type="text" class="hideOnLoad" size="15" maxlength="50" value="' . $rowZipCodes['county'] . '"
</td>
<td>
    <label class="hideOnEdit">' . $rowZipCodes['city'] . '</label>
    <input type="text" class="hideOnLoad" size="20" maxlength="50" value="' . $rowZipCodes['city'] . '"
</td>
<td>
    <label class="hideOnEdit">' . $rowZipCodes['zipCodes'] . '</label>
    <textarea class="hideOnLoad">' . $rowZipCodes['zipCodes'] . '</textarea>
</td>
```

You can see by the classes that I want certain elements to hide on page load and those elements will be shown on Edit. This line of jQuery properly hides the "hideOnLoad" classes elements:

```
$('.hideOnLoad').hide();
```

Then, I have javascript to detect when the Edit link is clicked and I call this function:

```
function EditTableRow(linkClicked) {

var id = linkClicked.attr('name');

$('a.hideOnEdit').fadeOut(500);
$('input.hideOnEdit').fadeOut(500);
$('textarea.hideOnEdit').fadeOut(500);

$('input.hideOnLoad').fadeIn(500);
$('textarea.hideOnLoad').fadeIn(500);
}
```

I knew as soon as I wrote the function that it didn't seem right, but I'm not sure how to implement what I need to do.

I'd appreciate anyone's suggestions on how to make this work as described!

Comment: Instead of generating hardcoded inputs, which is very heavy, why not generate them on click and have them replacing the content of the cell ?

Comment: @dystroy: I thought about that, but wasn't sure which would be better in terms of implementation vs "heaviness", as you put it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing's first, you don't want to call `$('.hideOnLoad').hide();` when the page loads. You run the risk of the user seeing the fields for a brief period. Instead add the following CSS. This is more likely to take effect before the user sees anything (but not guaranteed unless it's inline).

```
.hideOnLoad { display: none; }
```

As for your `EditTableRow` method, you're running it on everything rather than within the scope of the given row. Try something like this:

```
function EditTableRow(linkClicked) {
    var row = linkClicked.closest('tr');

    tr.find('.hideOnEdit').fadeOut(500);
    tr.find('.hideOnLoad').fadeIn(500);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I didn't mention it, but I am initially hiding the elements with CSS as you described.

This was the solution, though. I had to make some slight adjustments:
var row = linkClicked.parent().parent();
row.find('.hideOnEdit').fadeOut(500);
row.find('.hideOnLoad').delay(500).fadeIn(500);
Thanks, flem!

Answer (score 0):

```
HTML
<td>
    <label>value</label>
    <input id="val1" type="text" value="value">
</td>

JS
$('td').on('click', function(){
     $('input',$(this)).show();
     $('label',$(this)).hide();
});

$('input').on('blur', function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    $(this).previous('label').html(val).show();
    $(this).hide();
})
```